# How do I clear the "Hard" levels of Prof. Genki's Super Ethical Reality Climax?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I was playing some of the Hard variant of the "Genki" side-mission with a friend last night, and we both got demolished several times in a row.  There's one part where Brutes seem to spawn endlessly.  We got the exit open, but we couldn't survive long enough (and also didn't have enough time) to get to it.

We're both somewhat low level, since most of our play time is just screwing around at this point.  I feel like I should play a bit more and get more of the upgrades before we'll be able to tackle this.

What upgrades are worthwhile to have during PG-SERC?  Are there any ways to stop the infinitely spawning Brutes?  Are there any general strategies for this that you'd recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend doing everything in your power to finish the level as quickly as you can.  Don't worry too much about trying to earn a lot of money here, there are other things you could do in the game to get that.

To be able to do that, that means getting the money to be able to leave as fast as you can then race to the finish.  You'll need to have the right weapon upgrades and you need to be a crack shooter (mouse/keyboard combo is a necessity here if you have the PC version).

Accuracy is very important here as you can build up the multiplier for every kill you make but lose it if you ever miss.  I would recommend you come in equipped with any pistol at level 4 with the (optional) akimbo pistols upgrade and use this weapon exclusively for the first half of the level.  Akimbo pistols effectively doubles your ammo between reloads so not essential here.

Go for headshots on all the mascots.  One shot, one kill.  Try to do it as quickly as you can and don't miss!  Don't worry too much if you get hit, take your time, you can almost always find a health target nearby, just don't take too much hits.  When you have a high enough multiplier, go for the money shots for maximum effect.  When you have enough money, go ahead and switch to your strongest weapon (if you are able to earn presents) and go on to the finish.

When you encounter the brutes, it would be better to avoid them and *not* kill them (especially the first one).  As you know, they will respawn endlessly if you do.  But don't just try to run past them, you'll need to damage them enough to the point that they cannot move anymore (and you have the choice to finish them off).  Once they're in that state, *then* you can move on past them.

Otherwise, kill anything else in your path to the finish.

Comment: +1 This is what I did as well, damaged him enough to get the QTE prompt, then ran like hell.

Comment: You don't even have to be that accurate if you can string combos together; incendiary ammo will help with that. I completed both the Hard activities (on the 360) using mostly the Tek and the Gravedigger: points for kills plus one-shot when you get them plus head shot or nut shot, then pick off the money shot and ethical targets and avoid some traps. (I believe you can even avoid traps multiple times if you're near the exit but don't have enough cash to leave yet.)

Answer (score 0):

Having damage reduction from bullets and increased health and regen helps.

When you see the brutes you can try ducking behind these concrete platforms spread through out the level; if it's the same level I'm thinking, they're right before where the brutes spawn. The good thing about this spot is that they usually can't hit you.

I would kill a few of them and then just start running towards the exit; it's not worth it killing them over and over. Running and jumping also helps.

Comment: Can I regen health?  This seems to be disabled during this game mode.

Comment: You don't regenerate health, you can only get health hitting the health targets.

Comment: Oh bummer, forgot about that part :P

Answer (score 0):

Starting off, come in with high level pistols of your choice (dual wielding is great), and kill everything quickly. The only thing you shouldn't shoot are the **pandas**, as that is **UNETHICAL**. The only real obstacle here are the **Hunters** (brutes). Don't try to kill them, concentrate on the mascots and signs instead. There should be enough of both so that you can just run by the hunters and get to the finish with the requisite money.

### TL;DR

Shoot everything but the pandas, run away from the hunters.